# How to understand this output of Sed on MAC OS?

Tags: shell, sed

Command:

```sh
echo "aabb" |sed -n -E "s/([a-z])/\1/p"
```

Outputs:

```sh
aabb
```

Command:

```sh
echo "aabb" |sed -n -E "s/([a-z])([a-z])/\1/p"
```

Outputs:

```sh
abb
```

Command:

```sh
echo "aabb" |sed -n -E "s/([a-z])([a-z])/\1 \2/p"
```

Outputs:

```sh
a abb
```

Above 3 outputs confused me.

By my understanding:

- the 1st should be **a**;
- the 2nd should be **a**;
- the 3rd should be **a a**.

But the actual result is out of expectation. Why?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO that's because your regex is not complete you need to give `.*` in your regex like:

```
echo "aabb" |sed -n -E "s/([a-z]).*/\1/p"
```

By doing this we are exactly catching the one character and then matching rest of the line so hence its printing it fine.

why single `[a-z]` is not working: Because it looks only for a single character in line and when regex not matching anything so whole line comes in `\1` temp buffer hence its printing whole line.

Let's take an example where line has only 1 character then OP's regex will work eg-->

```
echo "a" |sed -n -E "s/([a-z])/\1/p"
```

***NOTE:*** Also you could remove `-n` and `/p` part too in your command and could use like:

```
echo "aabb" |sed -E "s/([a-z]).*/\1/"
```

Answer (score 2):

> But the actual result is out of expectation. Why?

It seems to me that you expect that the regex would replaces the whole line. It doesn't. It replaces only the matched part, the part of input that was matched against the regex. And only that part is substituted.

So for example:

```
echo "aabb" |sed -n -E "s/([a-z])([a-z])/\1 \2/p"
```

Regex matches:

```
aabb
^^       - those two characters are the _first_ match against ([a-z])([a-z])
^        - saved in \1
 ^       - saved in \2
^^ only this part is replaced by `\1 \2` which results in:
a abb
^^^   the replacement `\1 \2`
   ^^ the rest of the input is left untouched
```

Then only the matched part of input is replaced by the *replacement string*. So the part `aa` is replaced by `\1 \2`. The part of the line before or after the regex are left untouched.